# Angular Material themes should be created from a map containing the keys

Tags: html, css, angular, material-ui, angular-material

How do I rearrange my code to get it to fix the issue?

```
./src/styles.scss - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Angular Material themes should be created from a map containing the keys "color", "typography", and "density". The color value should be a map containing the palette values for "primary", "accent", and "warn". See https://material.angular.io/guide/theming for more information.

node_modules\@angular\material\core\theming\_theming.scss 186:5             define-light-theme()
node_modules\@angular\material\core\theming\_theming-deprecated.scss 26:11  light-theme()
src\styles.scss 9:27
```

```
@include mat-core();

// Angular Material Custom Theme
$cecini-client-app-primary: mat-palette($mat-grey, 800, 700, 900);
$cecini-client-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, 500, 900, A100);
$cecini-client-app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-red);
$cecini-client-app-theme: mat-light-theme($cecini-client-app-primary, $cecini-client-app-accent, $cecini-client-app-warn);
@include angular-material-theme($cecini-client-app-theme);
```

Tried various different versions of setting the angular material themes up and all of them resulted in same issue.